# best way to run a method inside service without disturbing Main UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-handler

I have a method which fetches the contacts from phone and send this to the php server for processing then it will return data so that it will update in the sql lite DB. I need to run this method continuously on background. I am using Volley for network operation. I am using Handler inside service to run this method. The problem is i am seen too many skipping frames and app is very slow and stucks. I want to run this method without disturbing the main thread. The service code is mentioned below.

```
public class serv extends Service {

ArrayList<String> aa= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> bb= new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject JSONimdb;
JSONObject EverythingJSON;
ArrayList<mobstat> musers = new ArrayList<mobstat>();
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
String l;
private static Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("Shiva","Service Killed");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
//nonstop1();
 threadcheck();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void _startService()
{
    long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask()
    {
       public void run()
       {
         try
          {
            getNumber(serv.this.getContentResolver());
          } catch (JSONException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
          }, 1000, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
 }

private void nonstop1()
{
   final Handler handlera = new Handler();
    Runnable updatea = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            try {
                getNumber(serv.this.getContentResolver());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handlera.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    };
    handlera.postDelayed(updatea, 10);
}

private void threadcheck()
{
    new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e("Shiva","Threadcheck");
                getNumber(serv.this.getContentResolver());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
   // Intent broadcatIntent = new Intent("com.statmob.findnum");
    //sendBroadcast(broadcatIntent);
    //stoptimertask();
  //nonstop1();
   threadcheck();
}



public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr) throws JSONException
{
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        if (phoneNumber.length()>=10)
        {
          l = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length()-10);
          aa.add(l);
          bb.add(name);}
    }
    phones.close();

    JSONimdb = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++)
    {
      try
       {
         JSONimdb.put(bb.get(i), aa.get(i));
       } catch (JSONException e)
         {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    EverythingJSON = new JSONObject();
    try
      {
        EverythingJSON.put("imdblist", JSONimdb);
      } catch (JSONException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://xxxxxxxx/cont.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s)
                {
                  if (s != null)
                  {
                    parseJSONresponse(s);
                  }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                  Log.e("Shiva",""+error);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
                {
                  Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                  params.put("arr", EverythingJSON.toString());
                  return params;
                }
            };

    int socketTimeout = 50000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    if(requestQueue==null)
    {
      requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(serv.this);}
      stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

private void parseJSONresponse(String s)
{
   try
      {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(s);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
        {
          JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
          musers.add(new mobstat(e.getString("name"), e.getString("status"),e.getLong("time")));
          SugarRecord.updateInTx(musers);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
 }
```

I have tried Timer & Handler, these are working fine but the it makes app slow and not responding. Thread is not working. Please suggest some better way to run this method in background without any disturb to main thread.

Answer (score 0):

create separate process for your service in manifest file might this help you

```
<manifest>
....
<application>
.....
 <service android:name=".serv"  android:process=":myprocess"  >
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)? It's an easy way of running time-consuming background task.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your current implementation with `IntentServices`.

By default `IntentServices` runs in background thread. If using `Services` it uses main thread by default. Then you need to run a `Thread` inside service to make that execution block in background.

Go through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and  [this link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html) for more information

Comment: but the method  getNumber(serv.this.getContentResolver()); run only once and i am not able to start the nonstop() handler inside intent service.